# Chromium: is communicating with the page faster than communicating with a worker?

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, v8, chromium, web-worker

Suppose I've got the following parts in my system: Storage (S) and a number of Clients (C). The clients are separate Web Workers and I'm actually trying to emulate something like shared memory for them.

Right now I've got just one Client and it's communicating with the Storage pretty intensively. For the sake of testing it is spinning in a for-loop, requesting some information from the Storage and processing it (processing is really cheap).

It turns out that this is *slow*. I've checked the process list and noticed `chrome --type=renderer` eating lots of CPU, so I thought that it might be redrawing the page or doing some kind of DOM processing after each message, since the Storage is running in the page context. Ok, I've decided to try to move the Storage to a separate Worker so that the page is totally idle now and… ended up getting even worse performance—exactly twice slower (I've tried a Shared Worker and a Dedicated Worker with explicit `MessageChannel`s with the same results).

So, here is my question: why sending a message from a Worker to another Worker is *exactly twice* slower than sending a message from a Worker to the page? Are they sending messages through the page? Is it “by design” or a bug? I was going to check the source code, but I'm afraid it's a bit too complex and, probably, someone is already familiar with this part of Chromium internals…

*P.S. I'm testing in Chrome 27.0.1453.93 on Linux and Chrome 28.0.1500.20 on Windows.*